# Addressing a List of Arrays

Tags: arrays, list, c#-4.0

im sorry if the question seems dumb but actually I tryed out everithing (i am a newbie in object programming so probably everithing wasnt really so).

Here the deal: i have a class made of one array (plus other useless stuff):

```
public class DataColumn
{
    private string nome_colonna;
    public string Nome_colonna
    {
        get { return nome_colonna; }
        set { nome_colonna = value; }
    }

    private double[] dato;
    public double[] Dato
    {
        get { return dato; }
        set { dato = value; }
    }
}
```

and i use it to build a list of such elements:

```
public class LogDati
{
    public List<DataColumn> DataColumns;

    public LogDati()
    {
        DataColumns = new List<DataColumn>();
    }
}
```

After that i declare it in my code:

```
public LogDati ld = new LogDati();
```

and i fill some of the useless data inside:

```
dc.Nome_colonna = values[kk].ToString();
ld.DataColumns.Add(dc);
```

As soon as i reach the "useful part" :) i got some problems: when trying to fill my data array in the list ld of the datacolumn class, it copies itself over and over.

```
for (int kk = 0; kk < numLogColumns; kk++)
                                {

                                    ld.DataColumns[kk].Dato[rowCounter] = Convert.ToDouble(values[kk]);
                                }
                                rowCounter++;
```

The issue is that the list results in having all the vector dato[] equal to each other.

Can anybody point me out why?
Thank you and please be patient, i am both new to this forum and object programming, and feel free to point out any suggestion.
Have a good day,
Paolo

EDIT 1:
Using the 2D array dbg it correctly assume the values desired

```
ld.DataColumns[kk].Dato[rowCounter] = Convert.ToDouble(values[kk]);                                        
dbg[kk, rowCounter] = Convert.ToDouble(values[kk]);
```

Comment: SOLVED thank to a collegue (after 8 hours):
i was missing the 
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(numLogRows);
instruction before the "add" one. 
I was adding the same column over and over again